# How to get least value from table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, min

I am getting the top value and least value from table,table accepting the nulls also.i am able to get the top value but not the low value.

This is my table data:

```
PostBidId UserId   PostId        BidAmount
-------------------------------------------------
1691       159       1239   
1684       147       1239        100000000000000
1683       147       1239        12345666666
1680       147       1239        6777777
1682       147       1239        900
1681       147       1239        90000000
```

My top value is `100000000000000`, low value id `900`.

This is my code:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    BidAmount AS HighestBid, '0' AS LowestBid 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Bids] 
WHERE
    PostId = 1239 AND BidAmount != '' 
ORDER BY
    BidAmount ASC
```

Output is: 100000000000000

```
SELECT
    MIN (BidAmount) AS LowestBid, '0' AS HighestBid 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Bids] 
WHERE
    PostId = 1239 AND BidAmount != ''
```

Output is: `100000000000000`, what I am expecting is: `900`.

Comment: Looks like `BidAmount` is a char column and a lexicographic ordering is applied.

Comment: @Zhorov i want for least value code,row_nuber() is not supporting, showing must have an OVER clause Error

Comment: Please [edit] your question according to the instructions in the [sql server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) to provide proper sample data. Types matter.

Comment: @Serg yes BidAmount column is varchar data type,how can i get least amount?

Comment: Convert it to a number type (`bigint` for example) in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT MIN (CAST (BidAmount as bigint)) AS LowestBid, '0' AS HighestBid
    FROM [dbo].[Bids] 
    WHERE PostId = 1239 AND BidAmount != ''
```

Comment: @Alinezhad after the sp i am calling this output  to my API (dotnet core)but getting the below error:Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.

Comment: @bharathim If you save `BidAmount`  in variable in your codes you need to change data type of that from string to int64.

Comment: if the  column have decimal values(233.89) those are not retrving. and in API side also getting convertion error.